# "parent directory is not writable" error in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a directory in `data/data` directory to host my files, but when I want to do this, I get an error: **directory of file is not writable: data/**

I can no do anything even creating `data/data/`

I am using Android level 7

```
File myFile = new File(Enviroment.getDataDirecotry() + "/" + "someFile.txt");
FileOutputStream stream = FileOutputStream (myFile);
stream.createFile();
```

I got problem after createfile , also I am not sure about correct code text used here .

Comment: Post your code what have you tried earlier..

Comment: might be a permission issue check your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in general access the file system from the root - you need to query the OS to get an appropriate root directory using getExternalStorageDirectory().

Furthermore you if you want to access most parts of the file system you will have to set up approriate permissions in the android manifest.

Comment: I do not want to use system files , I want to use data directory .

Answer (score 1):

first add the following tags in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

then you can use openFileOutput() method to create file in the `/data/data/<package_name>` directory.
eg:

```
OutputStream outStream;
outStream = openFileOutput( "test.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);

OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            outStream, "UTF-8");
                    outStreamWriter.write("this is a test");
                    outStreamWriter.close();
```